# How can I rewrite my loop so I directly loop over list items?

Tags: python, list, loops, indexing

So my code is

```
for i in range(len(temp1)-1):
   sim = similar(temp1[i][0],temp1[i+1][0])
   #and a few more stuff here
```

It is important that in every loop I compare two adjacent items from the list.

How can I write this part with direct access to list's items while avoiding nested loops?

I want something like

```
for item in temp1:
   sim = similar(item[0], next_item[0])
```

Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure if the duplicate is appropriate (but I think so). Please leave me a comment if it's not what you asked for.

Comment: @MSeifert I guess I'm looking for what is mentioned in the second answer as 'pairwise combinations' but I cannot understand how they are created using itertools functions. The accepted answer is what I have done and I want to avoid.

Comment: Maybe the third answer is what you're looking for `for item1, item2 in zip(temp1, temp1[1:]): sim = similar(item1, item2)`?

Comment: @MSeifert I guess that one should do the job, thanks :)